# Get rid of the european-citizens tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have the [eu-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-citizens) tag, which is very useful.

We also have the [european-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-citizens) tag, which is not.  What applies to a citizen of Finland will be very different from what applies to a citizen of Albania or the European parts of Russia or Kazakhstan.

I propose we get rid of the [european-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-citizens) tag.  I expect most of them should be tagged [eu-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-citizens) instead, and any others should be tagged by a non-eu country-specific tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the remaining questions and either removed the tag or retagged it [eu-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-citizens) dependent on the circumstances so this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score 4):

I agree, for the reasons given. The only thing that usually matters is whether a person is a citizen of a particular entity or not, and there is no such political entity as 'Europe'.

There should be tags for citizens of all political entities, where questions arise for those entities.

Comment: In started editing questions accordingly, but since these end in a review queue, better let anyone with more rep do that.